# Some features of Bootstrap are not working with Laravel after installation

Tags: bootstrap-5

I am new to PHP and Laravel.

I created a new Laravel project and did scaffolding with the following commands:

```
laravel new ig-app
composer require laravel/ui
php artisan ui vue
php artisan ui vue --auth
npm install && npm run dev
```

The laravel project is working. I can see some bootstrap fields. The problem is when I add some bootstrap classes like `.float-right`. It does not float right. Also, when I add a bootstrap dropdown, it does not toggle.

Nothing happens when clicking Dropdown button:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.10.2",
    "axios": "^0.25",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "laravel-mix": "^6.0.6",
    "lodash": "^4.17.19",
    "postcss": "^8.1.14",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.2",
    "sass": "^1.32.11",
    "sass-loader": "^11.0.1",
    "vue": "^2.6.12",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12"
}
```

composer.json

```
 "require": {
        "php": "^8.0.2",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
        "laravel/framework": "^9.2",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^2.14.1",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.7",
        "laravel/ui": "^3.4"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^6.1",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5.10",
        "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^1.0"
    },
```

Comment: If it's boostrap 5, the `-right` class have been substituted by the more global `-end` and `-left` became `-start`. This is to support RTL layouts more natively. Your dropdown probably still also uses the bootstrap4 code.

Comment: Thank you! It seems that is the case. Used bootstrap5 code and it's working.

Comment: Please do not use unrelated tags. Your problem is in no way related to Composer, npm, PHP, or Laravel